# PyMongo Replacing String in a Nested Document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Suppose I have a document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5cb3f4a098c73d1625970740"
  },
  "Dimensions": {
    "Dimension_1": "NaN",
    "Dimension_2": 1.5
  },
  "Other Dimensions": {
    "Dimension_1": "NaN",
    "Dimension_2": 1.5,
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5cb3f4a098c73d1625970740"
  },
  "Dimensions": {
    "Dimension_1": null,
    "Dimension_2": 1.5
  },
  "Other Dimensions": {
    "Dimension_1": null,
    "Dimension_2": 1.5,
  }
}
```

How would I go about switching every string `"NaN"` to `null` within the document using PyMongo?

Comment: Do you mean update values?

Comment: what is your mongoDB version & as GiovaniSalazar has asked do you wish to update the collection ?